# What does blue '?' over green mark mean in Unit Test Session window in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

[image]

Here is the printscreen. Cannot find the answer what these questions mean.

**Update.**

Found the answer. Which is quite simple. Will leave it here for those who may be interested.

*Question mark denotes that particular test was not run the last time unit tests were started.*

**Update.**
This UI is due to installed Resharper.
In clean Studio not run tests become grayed.

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it *as an answer*, not update your question and include it - that way it's easier for others to see that your question *has* been answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question mark denotes that particular test was not run the last time unit tests were started.

So this means that depicted result ma have changed.